# "import json" doesn't import the json.loads() function (I'm working with Flask here)

Tags: python

I'm using Flask on Visual Studio Community 2022 and I'm trying to access a json file and return the object.
Here's my code :

```
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index"

@app.route('/json')
def json():
    with open('json_file.json','r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the app server on localhost:4449
    app.run('localhost', 4449)
```

And here's the json file :

```
    "error": [],
    "id": 6
}
```

My problem is that whenever I wanted to access localhost:4449/json I get an error statement. Here's what my terminal returns :

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'loads'

I think it means it doesn't recognize .loads as a function and I don't know why. I also get the same error with the json.load() function.

Do you have an idea why this happens ?

Comment: `def json():` was a bad choice of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call that function `json`. You are also using module with that name. That would redefine the name of `json`.

Comment: It doesn't shadow the name; it redefines it. Both assignments (the `import` and the `def`) are in the same scope, so there are no outer and inner scopes, only the current scope with two definitions.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for noting it out. I will edit the answer.